# Handling csv files on Python

Tags: python-3.x, csv

I have to compare data from  different csv files on Python that consist of 84 columns and about 40.000 ~ 50.000 rows. This is a process that I need to do several times for several files. Which library should I use to have good performance? Should I use the regular csv library from python or would it be better to use something like Pandas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working with csvs usually will import the data in table formats. Typically R is a great language to manipulate columns and data in table (data frames) format, but when doing this in python, pandas is the go to library.